# Excel VBA Userform.Name as Variable to next Modul in case of Button Click

Tags: excel, vba, class, userform

i really need some help, im new to VBA programming and just learn all by myself. 
Thx for all Help.

**What is my problem ?**

I have more than 1 Userforms in my Tool and every Userform contains alot of Buttons some Buttons the same on other Userforms and some different. 
if i click a button in a Userform, the class cant give my userform.name as a variable to the next module.

in the Code "Class" sUserform is alltime "nothing"

**My Code
Userform**

```
Option Explicit
Private myBtn As clsCMD

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
modUI.ufGETICON Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

modMSG.ufINFO
modAUTOOPEN.Workbook_Open Me

Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In frmMain.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
            Set myBtn = New clsCMD
            Set myBtn.Button = ctrl
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Class**

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents Button As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Static collButton As New Collection
    collButton.Add Me
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click()

Dim sButton As String

sButton = Button.Name
CMDTEST *sUserform*, Button

End Sub
Private Sub CMDTEST(*sUserform As Object*, sButton As Object)



If sButton.Name = "cmd_Admin" Then
    modCMD.cmd_Admin
End If
If sButton.Name = "cmd_OItem" Then
    modCMD.cmd_OItem sUserform
End If

End Sub
```

**Modul**

```
Option Explicit
Public sUserform As Object

Public Sub cmd_Admin()
Dim sAnswer As String

sAnswer = InputBox("Passwort f?r den Zugang zum Adminbereich eingeben:", "Zugang Adminbereich")

If sAnswer = sPASS Then
    Unload frmMain
    frmMain.Hide

ElseIf sAnswer = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Inkorrektes Passwort eingegeben", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Passwortabfrage negativ"
End If
Application.Visible = True

End Sub

Public Sub cmd_OItem(sUseform As Object)

sUserform.Hide

frmOnIt.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: just a guess but could you use button.parent.name?

Comment: Thx for your quick help, but it dosent work bec. parent would be the frame and not the userform :(

Comment: button.parent.parent.name? That would work elsewhere, I just don't know if it work via a class

Comment: yes ofc it could work but the buttons on different levels so some button.parent.parent.parent.name some lower some higher ... i can get the name but i need it dynamic for a over all userforms

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but in the form initialise you could add ctrl.Tag = frmMain.Name   then you have it as a string of text - not an object reference - in the Button.Tag

Comment: yeah thx this was what i tryd but i just earnd some errors now i solved the problem read below

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to give you a precise answer without seeing how you want to apply this code across your Userforms.

If, for example, you're running the loops on each Userform, then couldn't you just add a Userform property to your class and pass in the appropriate Userform?

```
For Each ctrl In frmMain.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
        Set myBtn = New clsCMD
        With myBtn
            Set .Owner = frmMain
            Set .Button = ctrl
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Otherwise, I guess you'd just have to run up the control ladder until you find a Userform:

```
Private Function GetUserFormName(ctrl As Object) As String

    Do
        Set ctrl = ctrl.Parent
    Loop Until TypeOf ctrl.Parent Is MSForms.UserForm And Not TypeOf ctrl.Parent Is MSForms.Frame

    GetUserFormName = ctrl.Parent.Name
End Function
```

So your routine would contain code something like:

```
Private Sub CMDTEST(sButton As Object)
    Dim n As String

    n = GetUserFormName(sButton)
End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks to your help ill try this and will give you an answer tomorrow.

Comment: hey thank you for your tipps u can read below how i solved it maybe u can help me to improve my code

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem now and I'd like to hear your feedback if it's a good way or not. Maybe there are some improvements to do?

- You have to know this project is huge and i have more than 20 Userforms and over all Userforms more than 300 buttons. 
  Most of these buttons are like a Menu (laststep, nextstep, finish, cancel, OItem, Test, and some more). These are all doing the same every time, 
  and then i have some special buttons they are only 1-5 times on all userforms but these buttons should also doing the same on their Userforms (like refresh, change picture from Item, change something else etc.)
- I tested this code on a VBA Project on 3 Userforms

Code starting everytime from modAUTOOPEN, Auto_Open

**Userforms are:**
ALL Userforms have the same code at this time for this test.

- frmMain (starting site)
- frmOnIt
- frmTeM

.

```
Option Explicit
Private myBtn As clsCMD
Private myBtnColl As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
modUI.ufGETICON Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

modMSG.ufINFO
modAUTOOPEN.Workbook_Open Me

Dim ctrl As Control
Set myBtnColl = New Collection

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
        Set myBtn = New clsCMD
        Set myBtn.UserForm = Me
        Set myBtn.button = ctrl
        myBtnColl.Add myBtn
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Modules are:**

- modARCHIV
  (not relevant, just old material - maybe its useful in the future)
- modAUTOOPEN
  (standard stuff)

.

```
Option Explicit
Public sUSER As String
Public Const sPASS As String = "12345"

Public Sub Workbook_Open(sUSerform As Object)

modUI.ufPOSITION1 sUSerform

End Sub

Public Sub Auto_Open()

' User basierend auf Exceluser ausw?hlen
sUSER = Application.Username


modData.defDEFAULTS
modData.defWORKSHEETS

Load frmMain
frmMain.Show


End Sub
```

- modCHECKS
  (not relevant atm, checking which users are using the tool etc.)
- modCMD
  (where I program all my CMDs for every UF)

.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub cmd_Admin()
Dim sAnswer As String

sAnswer = InputBox("Passwort f?r den Zugang zum Adminbereich eingeben:", "Zugang Adminbereich")

If sAnswer = sPASS Then
    Unload frmMain
    frmMain.Hide

ElseIf sAnswer = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Inkorrektes Passwort eingegeben", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Passwortabfrage negativ"
End If
Application.Visible = True

End Sub

Public Sub cmd_OItem(sUfName As Object)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sUfName.Hide
frmOnIt.Show

End Sub

Public Sub cmd_Test(sUfName As Object)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sUfName.Hide
frmTeM.Show

End Sub
```

- modDATA
  (standard stuff)
- modFUNC
  (not relevant atm, for new functions)
- modLOAD
  (not relevant atm, load all datas to specific UF)
- modMSG
  (programming and updating all infoboxes on alle UF)
- modSAVE
  (not relevant atm, save all data from UF to WS or in new WB)
- modUI
  (checking how many screens and where to open, adding minimize button and windowstaskbar button, etc.)

**ClassModules are:**

- clsCMD (should the connection betweend buttons on UF and modCMD)

.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents button As MSForms.CommandButton
Private c_Userform As Object

Public Property Set UserForm(ByVal UfName As Object)
    Set c_Userform = UfName
End Property
Private Sub Button_click()

CMDTEST UfName, button

End Sub
Public Sub CMDTEST(UfName As Object, button As Object)

Dim sButton As String
Dim sUfName As String

sButton = button.Name
sUfName = c_Userform.Name

If button.Name = "cmd_Admin" Then
    modCMD.cmd_Admin
End If
If button.Name = "cmd_OItem" Then
    modCMD.cmd_OItem c_Userform
End If
If button.Name = "cmd_Test" Then
    modCMD.cmd_Test c_Userform
End If
'If Button.Name = "cmd_Auftragstool" Then
'    modCMD.cmd_Auftragstool c_Userform
'End If
'If Button.Name = "cmd_Beenden" Then
'    modCMD.cmd_Beenden c_Userform
'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You'll see that I've edited your post to remove some of the 'earthier' language and to clear up some grammatical ambiguities - feel free to roll back those edits if I've misunderstood, but try to keep your language clean. I'm not sure if you're aware but this site is specifically meant to solve problems, so you're unlikely to receive feedback on your answer. Better would be to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: oh Ok, thanks "but try to keep your language clean" ill try :/ im sorry.